# Re-run Batch File if 'Keyword' Exists

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to create a script that re-runs a batch file if a specific keyword is found within a log. The problem that I am having is with the function used to check the file. Currently, when I run this script it exits saying that the expression "does not match" even though the keyword does, in fact, exist within the log file. In this case, the log file to check is named is 'output.log' and the keyword to match is called 'temporary'.

```
$current_date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$file_path = "backup_" + $current_date
"checking in directory... --> " + $file_path

$word_to_find = "temporary"
$file_to_check = "output.log"

"Searching for matching expression '" + $word_to_find + "' in file: " + $file_to_check
$containsWord = $file_to_check | %{$_ -match $word_to_find}

if ($containsWord -contains $true) {
    'The expression matches, re-running batch feed.'
    start .\batch_script.bat
} else {
    'The expression does not match. Feed OK.'
}
```

Comment: Even if you were actually checking the content of the log, not its name, I'm not sure what the purpose is! _If `output.log` contains the string `temporary`, you want to run the `.bat` file which started this `.ps1` again. That means the string will still exist, and the 're-run' will continue until such time as the date changes, subsequently moving to another directory_.

Comment: @Compo I don't think we have the script here that produce the output.log file.
I hope it is a different script to tell you the truth.
Paxz got it right as Kieran did not use the file and he just gate the variable the value of "output.log".

Comment: okay, I see where I went wrong here. I want to search inside the contents of the file rather than comparing the file name string to 'temporary'.

Comment: @StefTheo, that's my point, based on the information provided, re-running the script will always find the same matching string until such time as `output.log` is modified or a different `output.log` is checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you first have to get the content of the log, atm you are just comparing the string `"output.log"` against the string `"temporary"`, which ofc returns the value 'false'.

If you want to keep your attempt, try it like this (Remember that output.log should either be in the running directory (than use `.\` like here) or you have to give the full path to the log file):

```
$current_date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$file_path = "backup_"+ $current_date
"checking in directory... --> " + $file_path

$word_to_find="temporary"
$file_to_check=".\output.log"

"Searching for matching expression '" + $word_to_find + "' in file: " + $file_to_check
$containsWord = Get-Content $file_to_check | %{$_ -match $word_to_find}

If ($containsWord -contains $true) {
  'The expression matches, re-running batch feed.'
  start .\batch_script.bat
}
Else {
  'The expression does not match. Feed OK.'
}
```

If you are up to some improvements, I would do it more like this:

```
$current_date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$file_path = "backup_"+ $current_date
Write-Host "checking in directory... --> $file_path"

$word_to_find="temporary"
$file_to_check="<fullPathToLog>\output.log"

Write-Host "Searching for matching expression '" + $word_to_find + "' in file:  $file_to_check"

If((Get-Content $file_to_check) -match $word_to_find) {
  'The expression matches, re-running batch feed.'
  start .\batch_script.bat
}
Else {
  'The expression does not match. Feed OK.'
}
```

This would save you the foreach and the extra variable.